# Sequelize.js joining an aliased assocation along with the non-aliased association

Tags: mysql, sql, join, associations, sequelize.js

I have a basic application with `Posts` and `Users`.  I'm trying to ensure that users are only presented with posts that meet the following conditions:

1. They have not seen this post before
2. They are not the author of this post

To that end, I have these associations:

```
User.hasMany(Post, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id'
});

User.belongsToMany(Post, {
  as: {
    singular: 'ViewedPost',
    plural: 'ViewedPosts'
  },
  through: UserPostView,
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  otherKey: 'post_id'
});

Post.belongsToMany(User, {
  as: {
    singular: 'ViewUser',
    plural: 'ViewUsers'
  },
  through: UserPostView,
  foreignKey: 'post_id',
  otherKey: 'user_id'
});
```

**I am able to satisfy each condition with a separate query, however, I'd like to be able to return Posts satisfying my conditions with a single query.**

Here is the query that I am using now to fetch posts that the user has not seen before.  How can I modify this query to also return posts that were not authored by the user?

```
function fetchFreshPost(user) {
  return user.getViewedPosts({
    attributes: ['id'],
    joinTableAttributes: []
  }).then(function(posts) {
    var postIds = _.map(posts, 'id');
    var query = {
      limit: 1,
      where: {
        id: {
          $notIn: postIds
        }
      }
    };

    return Post.findAll(query);
  })
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In your where clause you can adde $ne, something like

```
var query = {
      limit: 1,
      where: {
        id: {
          $notIn: postIds
        },
       user_id : {$ne : user.id}
      }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks @Keval — Unfortunately this still requires two queries, one `getViewedPosts` to get the user's viewed posts and then a second with the where clause.  I'm trying to combine this into one query.